# C# UDP Socket Listener Server - Start & Stop Buttons GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, backgroundworker, udpclient

I am very new to C# and Visual Basic etc, any help appreciated.

I am making a simple Form to listen to UDP ports.  I want to use buttons in the GUI to start and stop the UDP client.

So far the Start button works nice, makes a UDP client and starts receiving the constant flow of data, delivering it to a textbox in GUI.

However, I cannot make the Stop button work!

When I press Stop its like it ignores it and just carries on receiving, stuck in a loop! Any ideas why it doesn't work?  Maybe I should be using a backgroundworker but I cannot find any useful pages on how to implement that in my code.

Many thanks

Here is my code so far:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private UdpClient Client;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button_stop.Enabled = false;

            txtStatus.AppendText(">> Enter Port number and press Start! to begin ..." + Environment.NewLine);
            txtStatus.AppendText(">> Waiting for User to respond ..." + Environment.NewLine);

        }


        private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Client = new UdpClient(Convert.ToInt32(textBox_port.Text));
            Client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, null);

            txtStatus.AppendText(">> Connecting to Server..." + Environment.NewLine);
            button_start.Enabled = false;
            button_stop.Enabled = true;

        }


        private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(textBox_port.Text));
            byte[] data;
            try
            {
                data = Client.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);

               if (data.Length == 0)
                   return; // No more to receive
               Client.BeginReceive(DataReceived, null);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                return; // Connection closed
            }

            // Send the data to the UI thread
            this.BeginInvoke((Action<IPEndPoint, string>)DataReceivedUI, ip, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

        }

        private void DataReceivedUI(IPEndPoint endPoint, string data)
        {
            txtLog.AppendText("[" + endPoint.ToString() + "] " + data + Environment.NewLine);
            txtStatus.AppendText(">> Receiving!" + Environment.NewLine);

        }

        private void button_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
            Client.Close();
            txtStatus.AppendText(">> Stopped by user..." + Environment.NewLine);
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably getting an exception.  Add an exemption handler in the stop method and see what error message you are getting.

Comment: Hi thanks. Not sure how to do that. I tried putting a break point in the first line of button_stop_Click but does not get activated

Comment: The click event for the button isn't working.  Comment out the click event.  Then double click button on form  and see where the event method is located.  Either a new click event will be created or you will be sent to an existing button.